# How to call current temperature from openweathermap with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios

I am trying to do an axios call to get the latest temperature using openweatherapi. However for some reason I cant find out why my axios call is not working. Any help would be great, here is my code:

```
function Overview() {
    const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(0);
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(0);
    const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState('');
    const API_KEY = '{apikey}';

    const getLocationAsync = async () => {
        let {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            console.log('Location Permission Error')
        }

        const loc = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

        setLatitude(loc.coords.latitude);
        setLongitude(loc.coords.longitude);
    }

    const getTemperature = async () => {
        const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`;
        const response = await axios.get(encodeURI(url));
        const temp = await response.data?.main?.temp;
        setTemperature(temp);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        appState.current.match('active') ? setActive(true) : setActive(false)
        active && setInterval(() => setCount((oldCount) => oldCount + 1), 60000);
        getLocationAsync();

        return () => {
            clearInterval();
        };
    }, [active]);

    useEffect(() => {getTemperature()}, [longitude, latitude])

    return (
        <View style={{margin: 32}}>
            <View style={{marginBottom: 32}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 36, fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular'}}>Great!</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#878787', fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular'}}>Average mood 23%</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <OverviewContainer title="Weather" value={temperature ? temperature : "no data"} />
                <OverviewContainer title="Time on app" value={secondsToHms(count)} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Any advice on what im doing wrong would be great!

Comment: See [this link](https://dev.to/sandyabhi/fetching-data-from-weather-api-using-axios-in-reactjs-2bpg). The author shows how to solve a problem almost identical to yours.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried this and cant get it to work. I even copied the authors code and simplified it a bit but still couldnt get it to work! Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

You should change your `getWeather` function to the following.

```
const getWeather = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${api_key}`);
    setData(response.data.main.temp);
};
```

Comment: Ive changed my code to look like this but still get no data...

Answer (score -1):

You can get the data using `encodeURI()` function.

```
const getWeather = async () => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${apiKey}`;
    const response = await axios.get(encodeURI(url));
    const temp = await response.data?.main?.temp;
    setData(temp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call your getWeather function like below:

```js
const getWeather = () => {
             axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
                  lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${api_key}`)
            .then((response)=>setData(response.data.main.temp))
            .catch((err)=> consol.log(err))
                         }
```

Comment: Ive just updated my code to incorporate your change however it still does not work... any extra advise me great